# The code page 65001 is not supported by the server. for every bulk insert

Tags: sql-server

Running on my machine SQL SERVER 2016 SP2.

Every bulk insert I'm trying is giving me an error:

> The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.

Even if I'm trying to BULK INSERT from a file that doesn't exist, it is giving me the same error.

The origin file is encoded in UCS-2 LE BOM.

Comment: `65001` is UTF8, not UTF16. Importing UTF16 files into SQL Server works since the 1990s. What command did you actually use? What is the *actual* error?

Comment: Did you check the `Beta: utf8 support` setting in Windows' System Locale page?

Comment: There was bug reported for this issue in SQL Server 2017 and then later fixed in CU. Here is the link for the reported bug [`Bulk Insert Not Working`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35245150-bulk-insert-does-not-work-utf-8-support-enabled-fo) , I suggest you make sure that you have the latest updates applied to the sql server and then try again, if it still doesnt fix the issue, raise a ticket with MS.

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using SQL Server 2016? That was the instance that introduced support for Code Page 65001 in a `BULK INSERT`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"**\*\* Important \*\*** Versions prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding).*"

Answer (score 2):

Same issue happen in my env especially **EVEN the file doesn't exist**! I found that Panagiotis Kanavos and [link](https://www.cnblogs.com/kerrycode/p/13947080.html) solved my case.

You may try to unclick

***ControlPanel -> Region -> Administrative -> Change System Locale***

***Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support***

MyEnv:
Windows 10, SQL Server 2016 SP2(13.0.5102.14)